# What happens when import an existing project in ecilipse without copy it?

Tags: eclipse

Someone send me an folder and asked me to import it in eclipse. I found most tutorials online asks to select "copy projects into workspace" when importing it. (for example this one: https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/import-existing-projects-into-eclipse-workspace)

But it takes much longer when I select copy than without copy it. So I wonder what happens when I do not select copy? Is it linked to the original directory? Where are these link stored? If I change something, where the change is done, the original folder or in my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't copy the project then the project description that Eclipse creates specifies the original directory as the location of the project. All changes you make will be in that original directory.

The project location information is stored in the workspace metadata. It isn't really a link, just part of the project description. To be exact it is stored in the `.metadata/org.eclipse.core.resources/projects/<project name>/.location` file.

You can see the location in the Properties for the project on the Resources page in the Location field.